# Shrinking large DB file not working

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, shrink, vldb

I have a 5 TB database file (don't ask why) that I am cleaning up. I was already able to free over a TB and I will probably end up at 2.5 TB.

All best-practice advice aside, I need to now shrink this file. I am currently running this statement:

```
DBCC SHRINKFILE(1,4000000)
```

I can see that it is doing something, as it is sometimes waiting for a pageiolatch_sh and sometimes for a pageiolatch_ex. However, after 24 hours of execution time, the database has not shrunk by a single page. Usually when executing a file shrink like the above, you can see an impact on the file size immediately. Before, I tried to shrink the database by just a single GB and that also did not cause the file size to change at all. I stopped it after 24 hours.

This problem has been lingering for a while but we are at a point were we need to make progress, as the drive space is urgently required for other databases.

BTW, `DBCC CHECKDB` does not find any problems with that database, so this behaviour can't be caused by some circular page linkage.

Comment: Did you try running DBCC SHRINKFILE (1,TRUNCATEONLY)? It can be a good start since it doesn't try to move any data inside the file

Comment: Do you have BLOB or TEXTIMAGE data?

Comment: have you checked log_reuse_wait_desc column in the sys.databases system table?

Comment: @MatanYungman, I did, to no avail. The last extent of the file is in use...

Comment: @swasheck, yes. In fact most of the files is BLOB data (including the last extent)

Comment: @JamesAnderson, can't right now as a full backup is currently running. That will probably take until Tuesday... However. There is log shipping setup and we do not use any of the other log reuse preventing technologies, so this should not be an issue.

Comment: Clearly,  you are doing regular log backups?

Comment: Why are we addressing the log? He's trying to shrink the data file which is difficult when there's BLOB data

Comment: Is this file in the primary filegroup? If not, it may be faster to do an online rebuild to a different filegroup, and once everything is moved you can just drop the old file and filegroup.

Comment: It is the primary filegroup...

Comment: Have you determined that there is indeed space in the data file which is not being used?  If it is all used, unless you delete data or add another drive and move a table or two over, you aren't going to get it to shrink.  I have a script if you need it.

Comment: Related? http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2967240

Answer (score 1):

A colleague of mine had a similar-ish problem with long-running shrinks.  He took some time to investigate it and found that he had lots of indexes at the 'end' of the file.

A little index maintenance, and then the shrink operation ran fine.  You can read his blog about it here: http://sqltrees.wordpress.com/2013/08/11/shrinking-databases/